# Behavior of range in python and arange in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, range

Can someone please explain the '-5' below.
I'm somewhat new to numpy, but this seems bizarre

```
In [112]: an_int=9

In [113]: an_int/2
Out[113]: 4

In [114]: range(-an_int/2,an_int/2)
Out[114]: [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]

In [115]: arange(-an_int/2,an_int/2)
Out[115]: array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3])

In [116]: range(-4,4)
Out[116]: [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't numpy.  The "problem" is that integer division in python floors the result as opposed to truncating toward 0 (like the C language) -- e.g. `-9/2` *which is parsed as `(-9)/2`* (or `(-9)//2` if you're using python3.x) evaluates to `-5`.  The builtin `int` function on the other hand does truncate toward zero.  In other words:

```
a = -9
b = 2
print a//b #-5
print int(float(a)/b) #-4
```

If you're interested.  Here's a [blog post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) by Guido discussing this interesting (and maybe somewhat controversial) design decision.

Comment: Additionally, unary operator `-` has [higher precedence](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary) over `/`. So `-a/b` is `(-a)/b`, not `-(a/b)`.